# SQL Server - Query Taking Long Time with Hard Coded Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, performance, dblink

To preface, this query is using db_links into an oracle environment and is currently being executed in TOAD against the SQL Server database.

I initially had some date variables that the user can enter the date range, and when using these variables, the query executes in 15 seconds. When I hard code the same dates that I was manually inserting into the variables, the query now takes 3.5 minutes.

Why is my query going from 15 seconds to 3.5 minutes when I hard code the dates in rather than using date variables?

Here is the query below:

```
select TRANS.FGBTRNH_DOC_CODE,
       '' "calc1",
       TRANS.FGBTRNH_TRANS_DESC,
       case when TRANS.FGBTRNH_DR_CR_IND = 'C' then TRANS.FGBTRNH_TRANS_AMT *-1
              when TRANS.FGBTRNH_DR_CR_IND = 'D' then TRANS.FGBTRNH_TRANS_AMT
              end "calc2",
       CAST(TRANS.FGBTRNH_TRANS_DATE AS DATE) "calc3"
  from [BANTEST.UNWSP.EDU]..FIMSMGR.FGBTRNH TRANS
inner join [BANTEST.UNWSP.EDU]..FIMSMGR.FABINVH INVOICE on TRANS.FGBTRNH_DOC_CODE = INVOICE.FABINVH_CODE

where TRANS.FGBTRNH_ACCT_CODE = '19000'
       and TRANS.FGBTRNH_TRANS_DATE between convert(date,'08/01/2013') and convert(date,'08/31/2013')
       and TRANS.FGBTRNH_DOC_CODE not like 'J%'
       and TRANS.FGBTRNH_TRANS_DESC not like '%AMAZON%'
       and TRANS.FGBTRNH_POSTING_PERIOD <>'00'
       and ( TRANS.FGBTRNH_RUCL_CODE not like 'CA%'
         and TRANS.FGBTRNH_RUCL_CODE not like 'Y%' )
```

When I use the variables the conditional statement looks like this:

and TRANS.FGBTRNH_TRANS_DATE between :date1 and :date2

Toad then prompts for what the values of :date1 and :date2

Comment: And the statement takes so long also at the second execution using the same hard coded dates?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that stands out is the `CONVERT`.  Please try without it as follows:

```
TRANS.FGBTRNH_TRANS_DATE between '2013-08-01' and '2013-08-31'
```

Comment: I ran it with the parameters you provided and it ran in the same amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

When you use parameters ("variables"), the server can reutilize the execution plan, as the query is the same as one you've already executed.

If you don't use parameters, every time you change the dates, the server recognizes it as another query and has to build a new execution plan, which takes time.

Comment: While what you say is true, I find it hard to imagine that parsing is adding 3 minutes and 15 seocnds....(execution time goes from 15 seconds to 3.5 minutes.)

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak While you find it hard, doesn't mean it cannot occurs. I've seen it happens when using Linked Servers, which is the case. And I didn't talk about "parsing". I talked about "execution plan", which is a very different thing.

Comment: Even if I am executing either one of these two queries for the first time, they still take either 15 seconds with the variables or 3.5 minutes with hard coded dates. If I keep running the version with hard coded dates over and over without changing the dates, it still takes 3.5 minutes each time.